# While loop for change making

Tags: java

I am learning Java and am making code that converts pennies in to change. It is completed however, I am unsure what to enter for the while loop. I would have used `while(!change.equals("END"))` but this can't be done because change is an integer, so what can I do?

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
        int change = BIO.getInt();

        if (change <= 500 && change >= 1) {
            System.out.print("Amount" + "\t" + "Coins" + "\n");
        }

        while (change =) {
            int twopounds, pounds, fifty, twenty, ten, five, two, one;

            twopounds = change / 200;
            int left = change % 200;

            pounds = left / 100;
            left = left % 100;

            fifty = left / 50;
            left = left % 50;

            twenty = left / 20;
            left = left % 20;

            ten = left / 10;
            left = left % 10;

            five = left / 5;
            left = left % 5;

            two = left / 2;
            left = left % 2;

            one = left / 1;

            int nbCoins = twopounds + pounds + fifty + twenty + ten + five + two + one;

            if (change > 500 || change < 1) {
                System.out.print("Invalid amount " + change + "p" + "\n");
            }

            if (change <= 500 && change >= 1) {

                if (nbCoins == 1) {
                    System.out.print(change + "p " + "\t" + nbCoins + " coin ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(change + "p " + "\t" + nbCoins + " coins ");
                }

                if (twopounds > 0) {
                    System.out.print(twopounds > 1 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "200p ");
                }

                if (pounds > 0) {
                    System.out.print(pounds > 1 ? pounds + "*100p " : "100p ");
                }

                if (fifty > 0) {
                    System.out.print(fifty > 1 ? fifty + "*50p " : "50p ");
                }

                if (twenty > 0) {
                    System.out.print(twenty > 1 ? twenty + "*20p " : "20p ");
                }

                if (ten > 0) {
                    System.out.print(ten > 1 ? ten + "*10p " : "10p ");
                }

                if (five > 0) {
                    System.out.print(five > 1 ? five + "*5p " : "5p ");
                }

                if (two > 0) {
                    System.out.print(two > 1 ? two + "*2p " : "2p ");
                }

                if (one > 0) {
                    System.out.print(one > 1 ? one + "*1p " : "1p ");
                }

                System.out.print("\n");
            }

            System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
            change = BIO.getInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't you test for `0`? It seems like a legitimate choice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what BIO is.  Generally, there are options like .hasNextToken() if it is Enumerable.  But, without knowing what that variable is declared as, I can't tell you what your trigger would be.

Comment: It's an extension my university requires us to use, I don't know much about it.

Comment: Maybe you should review your study material, you'll probably find an explanation of how it works.

Comment: This is the definitive answer.  If you're reading a bunch of `ints` from some stream, you have to have some way of knowing when you're done.  That **might** be having someone input zero, but hopefully the stream will provide some more elegant way of saying "no more input remaining".

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
boolean flag = true;

while(flag){
    //do things 
    if(condition_when_you_want_your_loop_to_stop){
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't help because as strange as it sounds I need it to be possible for a negative number to be entered

Comment: ok so maybe you can declare a flag outside the loop whose default value would be trueand use that flag as while loop argument and set it to false inside the while loop whenever you feel like it :)

Comment: I'm sorry haha, could you possibly show me what you mean? I'm really new to Java... :)